# Angular 1.5 Pass data from component to controller

Tags: angularjs, components

I have component inside of the controller and i'm binding the data to it. How to make changes in component visible in the controller.
I have that code:

**JS**

```
app.controller('TheCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.changeable = 'earlier';
});

app.component('innerComponent', {
 bindings: {
  changeable: '='
 },
 controller: function() {
  this.changeable = 'later';
 }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="TheCtrl">
 <inner-component changeable="val"></inner-component>
 <p>
  {{changeable}}
 </p>
</div>
```

And it doesn't change the 'changeable' value in the view of the controller (it show "earlier" value). Why? How to make the changes visible in the controller?

Comment: first you are given $scope.val to inner-component... and for two way bindings works it should complex object not a primitive string like this...

Answer (score 1):

It does work as expected.

```js
function appCtrl() {
  this.value = "test";
}
var inner = {
 bindings: {
  changeable: '='
 },
 controller: function() {
  this.changeable = 'later';
 }
};

angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app')
  .controller('appCtrl', appCtrl)
  .component('inner', inner);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="appCtrl as ctrl">
    <inner changeable="ctrl.value"></inner>
    <p>
      {{ctrl.value}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However you shouldn't use components for building MVW apps.
You either go all the way and create a component root with children components or use "*controlled divs*".

But hybrid MVC/components apps are bad architecture.

Comment: what do you mean by bad architecture... what is wrong with using nested components?

Comment: <div ng-controller="TheCtrl"> is not a component. Nested components are good.

Comment: Maybe gyc was meant that nested components (and not using controllers at all) is more Angular 2 way and it is better to upgrade the app from Angular 1.5 to Angular 2.

Comment: What I meant to say is that mixing MVC pattern (ng-controller inside html elements) with components is not the best choice to build your app. You should use one or the other but not both. It's off topic though. Question answered :)